# tmux "freezes" when connecting via IPv6 (but not via IPv4)

Tags: ssh, ipv6, tmux

I connect from my Win 10 host to a Virtualbox Debian (bullseye) guest via zeroconf/mDNS - ssh - tmux. When I use IPv4 everything works as expected, with IPv6, tmux "freezes" after a couple minutes of inactivity， although input seems to still be sent to tmux, because when I reconnect to the tmux sessions all the sent input is there, it just wasn't displayed back.

I have observed similar behavior with a simple ssh sessions too, although there, the input eventually gets displayed, there's just a huge initial lag to it.

Comment: What VM system is the guest running on, and what network mode is being used?

Comment: Virtualbox, via the Host-Only Network adapter, no guest additions installed

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this problem, which was ultimately due to an old Win 10 firewall setting blocking *incoming* ICMPv6 traffic from the VM (specifically neighbor solicitations), thereby de-facto creating a very spotty IPv6 connection (unless a TCP connection was continuously kept busy) and causing the described weird upper layer behavior, like the SSH connection "falling asleep" and taking some time to "wake up" and tmux eventually just completely going haywire. A more detailed explanation for the underlying problem can be found here: https://superuser.com/a/1778991/902453