# What causes IPv6 ping of linux guest to drop packets in cyclical fashion on Win 10?

Tags: windows, networking, ping, ipv6

I'm trying to ping a linux virtual machine from a Win 10 host. IPv4 works perfectly fine, but trying to use a local IPv6 address drops packets cyclically in the following pattern.

Does anybody have an explanation for what's happening here?

```
ping -6 -t fe80::dead:beef

Request timed out.
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::dead:beef: time<1ms
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

I unwittingly "booby-trapped" the system in regards to IPv6 connectivity a long time ago by telling the windows firewall to `Block all incoming connections` on public networks. This hobbled IPv6 connections by only allowing one direction of IPv6's "neighbor detection/reachability" mechanism to work as intended, leading to the observed "working only in short bursts" pattern (for ping requests). Meanwhile, IPv4 connectivity was never affected since the equivalent ARP protocol is never blocked by the Win 10 firewall (due to being on layer 2). So for years everything worked fine and I forgot about even setting "block all" until one day I decided to finally start looking into using IPv6 for my machines.

[image: win 10 block all incoming connections firewall setting]

### Explanation:

#### IPv6 Neighbor Reachability Detection

Since ARP has always been something that "just works" (for my needs), I made the mistake to skip over how MAC resolution and neighbor reachability mechanisms work in IPv6. Turns out, two types of the ICMPv6 protocol (135, "neighbor solicitation" and 136 "neighbor advertisement") play the equivalent role to ARP requests/replies. And since the ICMPv6 protocol sits on top of IPv6, it is subject to firewall filtering rules like all other IPv6 packets.

Both the Win 10 and Linux VM have IPv6 "neighbor tables" (the equivalent of IPv4 ARP tables). On Win 10, this can be displayed with `netsh interface ipv6 show neighbors`, on Linux with `ip -6 neighbor`. Each entry has one of a handful of states (INCOMPLETE, REACHABLE, STALE, DELAY, PROBE, etc.).

I did not carefully read RFCs (see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861), but going by articles like (https://www.ccexpert.us/routing-tcp-ip-2/neighbor-unreachability-detection.html, https://mrncciew.com/2019/10/03/ipv6-neighbor-discovry/) in combination with real time observation of the neighbor tables and wireshark packet dumps, I come to the following conclusions:

- Neighbor table entries become "STALE" after 30 seconds of inactivity in case of TCP based connections.  In the case of connectionless UDP/ICMP(v6) packets, entries grow stale after 30 seconds regardless of activity, hence the host sends NS (on IPv6) or ARP request (IPv4) packets to query its counterpart, if a response is received, the state is set to "REACHABLE" for the next 30 seconds and so on.
- Win 10 and Linux seem to implement different amounts of (intermediary) states.
- Since the two hosts' neighbor table entries for each other can be in different states, and the Win 10 firewall only allows Win 10 -> VM neighbor solicitation packets to get answered, but not VM -> Win 10 NS packets, non trivial interactions can occur.

For example the observed "bursts" of successfully delivered vs. dropped echo reply packages are a byproduct of the Linux VM's neighbor tables entry being in the "FAILED" state upon receiving the first ping request and since its NS packets are not answered will return to this state and echo replies will not be sent. On the other hand, after Win 10 sends NS to refresh its own STALE neighbor table entry (and receives an NA answer), the Linux VM's corresponding neighbor table entry will now also temporarily be in a DELAYED state from which it can answer echo replies until the NA probes it sends out (three in total) time out and its state moves back to the FAILED state.

Alternatively, a non-stop **busy** TCP connection would also keep the Linux VM neighbor table entry constantly in the "REACHABLE" state so all ping requests would be answered.

#### The Firewall

As described, the main problems were:

1. Understanding that "ARP like functionality" is implemented via ICMPv6 in IPv6
2. Remembering having set a non-obvious setting years before.
3. Forgetting having set said non-obvious setting and concluding that "it can't be the firewall" since "I have whitelisted all ICMPv6 packets and it's still not working..."